# What is the quickest way to search in a large directory

Tags: java, search, directory

I'm implementing a file transfer tool in Java that will transfer some 'X' no. of files, where 'X' is configurable by user from one SFTP server to another. The transfer bit works but it can potentially pick up duplicate files (logic for which is not yet in place).

Now the SFTP_source server receives several hundred thousand files everyday and I'm not able to figure out how to perform a quick search to avoid duplicate file transfer in this behemoth list of files on the source server.

Or please also suggest if there's any better, faster way to achieve this without performing an expensive search operation? If searching through file names is the only way to go then what search paradigm to use?

Thanks.

Comment: What "search paradigm" have you tried? Why do you think it is slow and should be improved? Pseudo-code or actual code is better, as it will attract better answers.

Comment: @tucuxi: Currently, I'm looking at the server directory which lists over 6 million files. I'm so overwhelmed that I don't want to think. In short, I've not tried anything yet. But as a hind thought, I'm planning to list all the files in the directory in  a 'hashmap' and then simply iterate through it in order to look for duplicates. I posed the question so as to get an idea whether there are smarter ways to do this then simply iterating through the file list which might be expensive given the huge no of files.

Comment: The first thing to do with something big is to make it smaller. Can you adjust the upload process so that it creates more directories and fewer files in each? Can you move the files to another durectory after they have been transferred?

Comment: @EJP that's something I will need approval on from the business process but yes, that's a good option and I will try to propose it to the team. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

6M files is not *that* much memory. Experimentally, adding the string representations of the first 6M natural numbers to a `HashSet<String>` works with `-Xmx1G` and fails with `-Xmx512M`; and it only takes 2.5s on my machine (Java 8, 64-bit). Using a HashSet is therefore definitely feasible.

You can drastically lower the memory footprint if you are willing to sacrifice speed, by using the disk to store an index. In that case, you may be better of using an actual database - they are very well optimized to index and search large collections that would not fit in memory.

The code that I used for testing:

```
import java.util.*;
public class C {
    public static void main(String ... args) {
        HashSet<String> hs = new HashSet<>();
        long t = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i=0; i< 6 * 1000 * 1000; i++) {
            hs.add("" + i); // add returns "false" if key is already present
        }
        System.out.println("Added " + hs.size() + " keys in " 
            + (System.currentTimeMillis()-t));
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I tried the simple approach of listing all the files in a HashSet and then sorting them based on last modified in a loop and turns out it was a piece of cake for my simple machine. I'm getting all this done under two mins which is acceptable as there are other operations too.. using HashMaps also works equally good. Next thing to see would be if I can transfer files over to the SFTP faster than filezilla. I'm thinking to open multiple parallel connections, not sure if Filezilla already does that.

Comment: Transferring files real fast over a network is a very different question from detecting filename duplicates. If you need help with that, you should ask a different question (after some initial research effort). Opening multiple connections will only work if there is leftover bandwidth.

Comment: Thanks @tucuxi will do.